# MDNS activity-- is this a network risk/vuln?

Tags: attacks, wireless

I am connected to a wireless network that is huge (think large organization).  After opening up Wireshark and capturing pcap for about 15 minutes I am seeing lots of MDNS Standard Query traffic with devices and printers also connected to this network.

1) Is it weird that my machine is seeing this multi-cast traffic?

2) Is this something concerning/ a potential security risk?  For example, does the the nae "Joe's-Macbook.local" or a printer name being sent over the network open up an attack vector?

3) Should I be taking precaution so my information is not leaking out over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link about [what mDNS is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS).

Answering your questions:

1. No, is not weird. If it is a large network, lots of devices can be using that kind of protocol, like for example Apple Bonjour software packages.
2. If a hacker is on the network, of course any information could be useful. It is not a security risk itself, but can help.
3. The presence of mDNS packets on the network doesn't mean in any case a security risk. Anyway, take the standard precautions... use firewall, antivirus, use always secure protocols if available (SSL, SSH, etc).

Comment: Cool- thanks! What types of "network things" if you were the adversary/ attacker/ red team that you would look for in order to leverage from this traffic?

Comment: It depends of the info revealed. Maybe if the hostnames contain name and last name, you can use it for some kind of social engineering. There are some tools even for windows like this: [mDNS tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mdnstools/)